# Configure default dispatcher for all actors in config file

Tags: akka.net

Is it possible to set the default dispatcher for all actors in the system using only HOCON config or do I have to do:

```
Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<TActor>(propsArgs)
                    .WithDispatcher("my-fork-join-dispatcher"), actorName);
```

Ideally I would want to avoid having to configure this in code at all.

Comment: HI. Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Default dispatcher is set up from `akka.actor.default-dispatcher.type` section. When you'll look into [source code](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Configuration/Pigeon.conf#L275), you can see, how it's configured by default.

Comment: I am trying to configure a fork-join dispatcher, but can't make it work using the example from your link. Can you spot the errror:
my-fork-join-dispatcher{
        type = ForkJoinDispatcher
        throughput = 60
        dedicated-thread-pool{
          thread-count = 3
 }
}
akka {          
 actor{
  logConfigOnStart = on
 }
 default-dispatcher {
  type="my-fork-join-dispatcher"
  }
}

Comment: You can read more details on each config option in the comments under the link I've attached, especially `default-dispatcher.type` and `default-dispather.executor`. (*FQCN mean fully qualified class name with assembly name*). "my-fork-join-dispatcher" value is invalid there, as it's pointing to a config entry, while it should be either one of the predefined dispatchers or a qualified type name for a custom one. I don't know how much your dispatcher differs from existing ones, but maybe setting `default-dispatcher.executor = fork-join-executor` is all you need.

Comment: Maybe that is enough if I can still set thread-count and throughput since I need to configure that different per environment we deploy to